# How typechecking works in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, compiler-warnings, typechecking

I am curious about how type checking works with Swift, I have played around a little bit and created a `Living` class, and an `Animal` class which inherits from `Living` class. A `Cat` class inherits from `Animal` class, and a `Dog` class which does not have any parent class.

My class hierarchy so far:

```
class Living {
  let heartRatePerMin: Int
  init(heartRatePerMin: Int) {
      self.heartRatePerMin = heartRatePerMin
  }
}

class Animal: Living {
  let name: String

  init(name: String, heartRatePerMin: Int) {
      self.name = name
      super.init(heartRatePerMin: heartRatePerMin)
  }
}

class Cat: Animal {
  let meowsPerHour: Int

  init(meowsPerHour: Int, name: String) {
      self.meowsPerHour = meowsPerHour
      super.init(name: name, heartRatePerMin: 60)
  }
}

class Dog {
  let runningSpeed: Int

  init(runningSpeed : Int) {
      self.runningSpeed = runningSpeed
  }
}
```

Firstly when I create instances of animal, dog, and a cat. I get warnings about if a check will always fails or successes. The way I check types and get the warnings:

```
let animal = Animal(name: "Daisy", heartRatePerMin: 80)
let dog = Dog(runningSpeed: 2)
let cat = Cat(meowsPerHour: 10, name: "Smokey")

    if animal is Animal {
        //Warning: 'is' test always true
    }

    if dog is Animal {
        //Warning: Cast from 'Dog' to unrelated type 'Animal' always fails
    }

    if cat is Animal {
        //Warning: 'is' test always true
    }

    if cat is Living {
        //Warning: 'is' test always true
    }
```

So far, I believe that compiler checks if a given object class has inheritance to type being checked and can give warnings.

Then I created an empty `Grumpy` protocol:

```
protocol Grumpy {

}
```

After that, I conformed to Grumpy from my `Cat` class, but I did not conform from my `Dog` class.

Now, when I check if the type of my objects (cat, and dog) are Grumpy as following, I get the warning for cat as `Cat` class conforms to Grumpy protocol, but I do not get any warning for dog. It does not say anything. But when I checked for dog if it is Animal type above, it was giving the warning that it will always fail. Why it cannot give the same information for this case?

```
    if cat is Grumpy {
        //Warning: 'is' test is always true
    }

    if dog is Grumpy {
        //Nothing
    }
```

Then given my lack of CS and Swift knowledge I also tried to do something else to see how it will behave, I have created an array of `Any` as `anyArray`. Then created a variable `unknown`, casted `cat` as `Any` to be equal to `unknown`. Then appended `unknown` to `anyArray`. After that, I tried to type check if first index of `anyArray` is type of `Cat`, but again no warning:

```
    var anyArray = [Any]()
    let unknown = cat as Any
    anyArray.append(unknown)

    if anyArray[0] is Cat {
        //Nothing.
    }
```

So given all the things I tried, Im curious about how the type checking works, for both compile time and run time? I know it was a bit long question, but any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know that the following is valid and why:

```
// although living is of type Living, it stores an instance of Cat at runtime
let living: Living =  Cat(meowsPerHour: 10, name: "Smokey")
```

Let's examine this first:

```
if dog is Grumpy {
    //Nothing
}
```

`dog` is of type `Dog`, but the compiler doesn't not know if at runtime, `dog` will store a subclass of `Dog`, which does conform to `Grumpy`. The if statement will be run if `dog` is assigned like this:

```
class GrumpyDog : Dog, Grumpy {
    // ...
}

dog = GrumpyDog(...)
```

---

```
if anyArray[0] is Cat {
    //Nothing.
}
```

This is because `anyArray[0]` is of type `Any`. The compiler is not smart enough to know that at runtime, `anyArray[0]` stores a `Cat`. Therefore, it cannot be sure that `is` will evaluate to true. "What if it actually is a `Dog`?" it might say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for example at last point since the compiler is not smart enough, when we run the application, does the compiler try to cast that object as Cat under the hood? If so, how does it do it? Create some space in memory to cast it? Then if it succeeds or fails, does it remove that space in memory used to check the type? @Sweeper

Comment: @emrepun When we run the application, the compiler is involved. Compilers compile source code. They don't run programs. At runtime, the runtime knows exactly what type each variable stores. No memory needs to be allocated. The runtime just checks whether `anyArray[0]` stores an instance of `Cat` or one of `Cat`'s subclasses.